# how to set environment variable in Solaris (in .profile)

Tags: solaris, environment-variables, user-profile

how do I set an environment variable in my .profile file that takes into account if the variable exists and appends to it?

To explain:

I want to do

```
export ANT_OPTS=-Dparam=value
```

but if the ANT_OPTS already exists I want to append to it.

I want to do something similar to

```
set ANT_OPTS=%ANT_OPTS% -Dparam=value
```

in Windows.

How do I create it or append to it if it already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`export ANT_OPTS="$ANT_OPTS -Dparam=value"`

Comment: it worked like a charm. I was trying **export ANT_OPTS=$ANT_OPTS -Dparam=value** but it didn't work. It didn't occur to me to also add the quotes. Thanks!